# Destroyed GameObject but still trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**EntryPoint.cs**

```
protected IEnumerator LoadAsync(string prf_path, Transform prt_tf, bool is_enable = true)
{

    ResourceRequest res_req = Resources.LoadAsync<GameObject>(string.Format(prf_path, quality));
    res_req.priority = 0; // = ThreadPriority.Low;
    yield return res_req;

    if (res_req == null || res_req.asset == null)
    {
        res_req = Resources.LoadAsync<GameObject>(string.Format(prf_path, "HIGH"));
        res_req.priority = 0; // = ThreadPriority.Low;
        yield return res_req;
        Debug.LogFormat(prf_path, "HIGH");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogFormat(prf_path, quality);
    }

    GameObject prf = res_req.asset as GameObject;
    GameObject obj = Instantiate(prf);

    obj.transform.SetParent(prt_tf);
    obj.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    obj.transform.localRotation = prf.transform.localRotation;
    obj.transform.localPosition = prf.transform.localPosition;
    obj.name = prf.name;
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    obj.SetActive(is_enable);
}
```

LOBBYUI:
I have an option which is Option `Rendering` and Option `Livestreaming`. Now here's the problem . When i tried to run my program for the very first time and choose Option `Livestreaming` it will work then i'll logout then it will go back to my LobbyUI and choose the Option `Rendering`. Then this error will come out

> Object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

Now when i tried this line of code

```
if (obj != null)
    {
        obj.SetActive(is_enable);
    }
```

It will point out to my object which is initiated and that's pretty weird . Any idea?

## EDIT:MORE INFO

I load my resources using this line of code:

**MC_EntryPoint: EntryPointA**

```
 if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt(OptionPopup.LiveStreaming_) == 1)
    {
        tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 1~2)");
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/logo", tf));
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/card_open_window", tf));
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/ranking", tf));
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/streaming_feed", tf));

        tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 10~11)");
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/midterm_loading", tf));

        tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 12)");
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/game_result", tf));
    }
    else
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/minimap_type_b (x_ 1575, 1356)", tf));
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/replay", tf));

        tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 1~2)");
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/logo", tf));
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/card_open_window", tf));
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/ranking", tf));
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/top_bar", tf));

        tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 10~11)");
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/midterm_loading", tf));

        tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 12)");
        yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/game_result", tf));
    }

    loading.SetValue(0.02f);    // 2%.
```

So it's something like . Is there any other way load some of my **UserInterface** if i'm from `Livestreaming`(which i do not load some UI) to `Rendering` (which i load some UI).

**EntryPointA:EntryPoint**

```
protected override IEnumerator Init()
{
    tzPlayInfo.Instance.BLOCK_GAME_FLOW = true;
    tzPlayInfo.Instance.MAKING_GAME_OBJECT = true;
    //start_time = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    loading.SetValue(0f);       // 0%.

    yield return StartCoroutine(InitSystem());
    //Debug.Log(string.Format("End InitSystem - {0}s", Time.realtimeSinceStartup - start_time));
    loading.SetValue(0.01f);    // 1%.

    yield return StartCoroutine(InitUI());
    //Debug.Log(string.Format("End InitUI - {0}s", Time.realtimeSinceStartup - start_time));
    loading.SetValue(0.05f);    // 5%.

    yield return StartCoroutine(InitGO());
    //Debug.Log(string.Format("End InitGO - {0}s", Time.realtimeSinceStartup - start_time));
    loading.SetValue(0.95f);    // 95%.

    yield return StartCoroutine(InitServerDependentInfo());
    //Debug.Log(string.Format("End InitServerDependentInfo - {0}s", Time.realtimeSinceStartup - start_time));
    loading.SetValue(0.96f);    // 96%.

    yield return StartCoroutine(Recheck());
    //Debug.Log(string.Format("End Recheck - {0}s", Time.realtimeSinceStartup - start_time));
    loading.SetValue(1f);       // 100%.
    CameraManager.Instance.TurnOnCamera(eCmr.PADDOCK_1); // 로딩이 끝나면 카메라를 켠다.
    tzPlayInfo.Instance.BLOCK_GAME_FLOW = false;

    Destroy(loading.gameObject);    // 첫로딩 UI 삭제.
    Destroy(this);                  // EntryPoint 컴포넌트 삭제.
}
```

## EDITTED QUESTION

I guess the information I provided was a bit stiff so i edited it. And i'm guessing that it is null because I destroy something??? Please enlighten me.

Comment: Out of topic: That method naming will be source of confusion in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question . What i did here is that this line of code

```
protected IEnumerator LoadAsync(string prf_path, Transform prt_tf, bool is_enable = true)
{

    ResourceRequest res_req = Resources.LoadAsync<GameObject>(string.Format(prf_path, quality));
    res_req.priority = 0; // = ThreadPriority.Low;
    yield return res_req;

    if (res_req == null || res_req.asset == null)
    {
        res_req = Resources.LoadAsync<GameObject>(string.Format(prf_path, "HIGH"));
        res_req.priority = 0; // = ThreadPriority.Low;
        yield return res_req;
        Debug.LogFormat(prf_path, "HIGH");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogFormat(prf_path, quality);
    }

    GameObject prf = res_req.asset as GameObject;
    GameObject obj = Instantiate(prf);

    obj.transform.SetParent(prt_tf);
    obj.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    obj.transform.localRotation = prf.transform.localRotation;
    obj.transform.localPosition = prf.transform.localPosition;
    obj.name = prf.name;
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    obj.SetActive(is_enable);
}
```

Doesn't work on Android Phone . It's basically for PC Platform only . So right now currently I'm making a method for Mobile. I'll edit my answer after i finish this up. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Unable to comment but did you check that you are not trying to access that gameObject from other place? may be any reference ? Or you are using singleton?

Comment: I'm using a singleton . but damn this is a big project so it's hard to adopt

Comment: Object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. which line it is pointing?

Comment: it's pointing here `obj.SetActive(is_enable);` it's on my question on the very top

Comment: could you try to use StopAllCoroutines() before scene changing?

Comment: Where should i put that??

Comment: OnDestroy of the script where LoadAsync belongs

Comment: I edited my question sir . Try reading it again it might help.